# About minimal basic open sets

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

If $f$ is a continuous function from a finite space to another finite space does the image of minimal basic open set at a point $x$ in the domain is equal to the minimal basic open set at $f(x)$ in the co-domain or not?

Answer (score 1):

Consider the identity $i:(X,\tau_1)\to (X,\tau_2)$, being $\tau_1$ and $\tau_2$ the discrete and the concrete topology, respectively.